# Using ICU classes and methods from C#

Tags: c#, icu

I'd like to use ICU classes and methods from within a C# application - specifically the break interators and associated types. My guess is that I use DllImport to reference the ICU4C dll's but I'm not sure how to pass types like ICU strings. Will .NET marshall these for me? Are the libraries that come in the binary distribution COM compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [ICU4NET](http://code.google.com/p/icu4net/):

> ICU4NET provides binding for .NET language over ICU4C.

It sounds like it would be exactly what you need - if it works. Admittedly the last "release" was 0.0.3 and the last change was in August 2010, but it would still be a useful starting point, I'd suggest.

(You may find that it works as far as it's gone, but that as it's fulfilled everything the original author needed, that's as far as it went. If you could contribute changes to it as required, that would benefit future developers in the same position...)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I thought I'd already looked at this but on second look it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is an alternative: [icu-dotnet](https://github.com/sillsdev/icu-dotnet)

Looks like the Lucene.net team is changing from ICU4NET to icu-dotnet for the [following reason](http://search-lucene.com/m/j1zMf1dCWfJA7ZSk&subj=RE+Lucene+NET+to+NET+Core):

> In regards to ICU4NET, we replaced ICU4NET with icu-dotnet (https://github.com/sillsdev/icu-dotnet).  We decided to change the library because ICU4NET is a uses a small C++/CLI wrapper around the original library but there are currently no plans to move C++/CLI to cross-platform. icu-dotnet uses PInvokes instead.

I was hoping they would move off of ICU4NET since the nuget packages are only targeted for x86.